# What is the "right" way to debianize software that uses the scons build-system?

Tags: compiling, packaging

What specific tools are available, if any, or should we just use a fake Makefile that runs scons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `debian/rules` file is a Makefile. Anything you might want to do in a "fake" Makefile, you can just do there. The [`dh` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dh) is a helper that will run most build systems with Debian defaults for you. I believe it supports `scons` If so, all you need is:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@
```

You can override its default behavior if you need to pass custom options (or if it doesn't really support `scons`). Then your rules file might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

SCONS=scons 

%:
    dh $@

override_dh_auto_build:
    $(SCONS) --prefix=$(DEB_DESTDIR)/usr

override_dh_auto_clean:
    dh_auto_clean
    $(SCONS)  -c

override_dh_auto_install:
    $(SCONS) install --prefix=$(DEB_DESTDIR)/usr
```

Sometimes, the best way to learn how to do something is to look at how other packages do it. The command:

```
reverse-depends -b scons
```

will list all packages that Build-Depend on `scons` Grab their source and see the different ways they build.